# Bad HTTPS cert: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok" in Webworker

Tags: javascript, https, web-worker, webassembly

## I'm trying to run Webassembly inside a Webworker

I can load `heavyLifting.wasm` perfectly fine the traditional way (aka not in a webworker) but trying to load it inside a webworker runs into warnings (not errors actually). Here's how I loaded it:

```
// worker.js
self.importScripts('heavyLifting.js');
```

And the warning:

```
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok
```

From what I gather, it finds the file - but I assume it has something to do with it not being HTTPS.

I actually haven't tried serving it through HTTPS yet (because locally serving HTTPS has become a lot more difficult for some reason). However, does anyone have any knowledge that might save me a few more hours of banging my head against the wall? Did I forget some setting or config? Why would a webworker be extra picky about what wasm it serves (because as I mentioned, I'm able to serve up my wasm fine as a regular script)

#### Update:

It wasn't an HTTPS error - it had to do with `importScript()`.

```
worker.js
js/
  heavyLifting.js   // glue code
  heavyLifting.wasm
```

This was all fixed by moving `worker.js` down into the `js` folder.

I immediately ran in to the following error:

```
'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.'
```

It turns out the node package `http-server` doesn't serve wasm properly, but the python3 `http.server` does.